# Simple ajax GET request not working on my Django webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I'm very new to both Django and Ajax (it's my first time using both) and I am receiving an error with my code. Basically I have an HTML button, on a webpage generated by a template in Django, that should call a function onclick which is assigned using jquery. When clicked, the button should send a GET request to the webpage with the specified url. That's all I want it to do, however, it just does not seem to work. It keeps throwing an error. Here is some of the code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary toChange">Click me</button>
```

and

```
    $(".toChange").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'localhost:8000/MyApp/ajax_test',
            type: 'GET', 
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        }); 
      //alert("Something happened!")
    });


</script>
```

and my view for what I'm trying to get is:

```
def test(request):
    return HttpResponse("Congrats, you've got it!")
```

Currently, I am using firefox to look at the webpage on localhost:8000. If I look at the console when I click the button, this is what I see.

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"[Exception... \"<no message>\"   nsresult: \"0x805e0006 (<unknown>)\"  location: \"JS frame :: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js :: .send :: line 5\"  data: no]"}

AJAX error: error : [Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js :: .send :: line 5"  data: no]
```

I tried researching the errors and I'm not sure but it could be an error with firefox not allowing the request to go through. Can someone help me please?

Comment: instead of `url: 'localhost:8000/MyApp/ajax_test',`; could you please try `url: '//localhost:8000/MyApp/ajax_test',`

Comment: Oh wow, both this and another answer worked. If you could, could you please explain what was wrong? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your url from:

```
$(".toChange").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'localhost:8000/MyApp/ajax_test', # change here
```

to

```
$(".toChange").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/MyApp/ajax_test',
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! What was wrong with what I had before, was it putting in unnecessary data in the url?

Comment: It would be great if you accept this answer by clicking the tick mark beside the answer, so that other users may find it useful in future. :)

Comment: Oh sorry, there ya go

Comment: actually the url you have provided is not actually a valid url. You needed to use either `//localhost:8000/...` or `http://localhost:8000/...` or simply `/MyApp/...`